# .NET MVC 3 - Unwanted Horizontal Scroll Bar

Tags: css

I have a page which is displaying the text of a book with pictures included in it. I have a problem where a horizontal scroll bar is displayed in certain circumstances. The CSS is as follows:

```
#textDisplay
{
    width: 704px;
    height: 750px; 
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x; auto;
}

.picture 
{ 
    font: 13px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic; 
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
}

.picture img 
{ 
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
} 

.left 
{
     margin: 0 20px 10px 20px; 
     float: left; 
}
```

The #textDisplay is used in a div that surrounds the entire text. The definition of the picture is as follows:

```
<div class="picture left">
    <img src="../../../../Content/Images/BookPhotos/Men Bowlers 1953.jpg" alt="Men Bowlers 1953 - drawings by Cyril Thompson" />
    <br />Men Bowlers 1953 – drawings by Cyril Thompson
</div>
```

If I follow that with a paragraph tag p, then a horizontal scrollbar is displayed. If however I precede or follow it with a h4 tag, the scrollbar is not displayed.

Their definitions are:

```
p
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
    margin: 15pt 20px 15pt 20px;
}

h4
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}
```

Anybody any ideas why this should be so and how I can fix it?

It doesn't happen in Firefox nor Chrome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Take a look at:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow

Comment: I do want a vertical scroll bar. I have tried overflow-x: none; and overflow-x: hidden; but I still get a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Do you have a live site I can see?

Comment: http://testdir1.royalleamingtonspabc.org.uk - go to History Quarter / Bowling Along for 100 Years and select Chapter 6. The second and fifth photos are the ones that are causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thirtydot, that worked for me, too.

I had a wrapper div below my body tag and it had horizontal overflow that made an unwanted scroll bar.

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

This did the trick. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the whole html code after body tag, Example:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
//all the html code
</div>
</body>
```

Wrap everything inside div class "container-fluid", simple and easy way around!

Works all the time for me!!